# nutch server that outputs to solr

Tags: solr, nutch

I have rest nutch server I'm able tocreate jobs and everything.

1. How can I configure the nutch server to output to solr? didn't find any configuration to that in the conf files (nutch-site, nutch-default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to configure the required parameters of Nutch (`http.agent.name`) and just indicate that you want to index your content in the desired Solr instance, for instance using the `bin/crawl` script you'll just need to add the `solr.server.url` property:

```
$ bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/ urls/ crawl/ 2
```

If you execute `bin/crawl` in the terminal you'll get more information about the available options. A more comprehensive introduction is [available here](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial). For the 2.x branch the `bin/crawl` script has some differences.

Just set the `solr.server.url` through the configuration endpoint, and then create the Index Job, this should do the trick:

```
POST /job/create
{  
    "type":"INDEX",
    "confId":"new-config",
    "crawlId":"crawl01",
    "args": {}
}
```

More information about this endpoint could be found [here](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch_1.X_RESTAPI/RunningJobsTutorial/IndexJob)

Comment: btw - I guess there is error in the documentation you referred, as the url doesn't contain the collection name...

Comment: Perhaps the documentation is a bit out of sync with the actual implementation, the API is under active development, if you could file a JIRA in https://issues.apache.org/jira/ it would be great, the documentation could be out of sync, I'll take a look at it later today.

Comment: in me POST create job in the last step "INDEX" I keep getting "java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing SOLR URL. Should be set via -D solr.server.url
SOLRIndexWriter" though I put the solr.server.url in the args (this is the last POST step, all steps before were successful. Am I missing another requirement here?

Comment: opened a new question for that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345524/apache-nutch-to-index-to-solr-via-rest