# apache nutch to index to solr via REST

Tags: apache, solr, nutch

newbie in apache nutch - writing a client to use it via REST.
succeed in all the steps (INJECT, FETCH...) - in the last step - when trying to index to solr - it fails to pass the parameter. 
The Request (I formatted it in some website)

```
{
  "args": {
    "batch": "1463743197862",
    "crawlId": "sample-crawl-01",
    "solr.server.url": "http:\/\/x.x.x.x:8081\/solr\/"
  },
  "confId": "default",
  "type": "INDEX",
  "crawlId": "sample-crawl-01"
}
```

The Nutch logs:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing SOLR URL. Should be set via -D solr.server.url
SOLRIndexWriter
        solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance (mandatory)
        solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
        solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
        solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
        solr.auth.username : username for authentication
        solr.auth.password : password for authentication
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
```

Was that implemented? the param passing to solr plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create/update a configuration using the `/config/create/` endpoint, with a POST request and a payload similar to:

```
{
    "configId":"solr-config",
    "force":"true",
    "params":{"solr.server.url":"http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/"}
}
```

In this case I'm creating a new configuration and specifying the `solr.server.url` parameter. You can verify this is working with a GET request to `/config/solr-config` (`solr-config` is the previously specified `configId`), the output should contain all the default parameters see https://gist.github.com/jorgelbg/689b1d66d116fa55a1ee14d7193d71b4 for an example/default output. If everything worked fine in the returned JSON you should see the `solr.server.url` option with the desired value https://gist.github.com/jorgelbg/689b1d66d116fa55a1ee14d7193d71b4#file-nutch-solr-config-json-L464.

After this just hit the `/job/create` endpoint to create a new `INDEX` Job, the payload should be something like:

```
{
    "type":"INDEX",
    "confId":"solr-config",
    "crawlId":"crawl01",
    "args": {}
}
```

The idea is that need to you pass the `configId` that you created with the `solr.server.url` specified along with the `crawlId` and other args. This should return something similar to:

```
{
  "id": "crawl01-solr-config-INDEX-1252914231",
  "type": "INDEX",
  "confId": "solr-config",
  "args": {},
  "result": null,
  "state": "RUNNING",
  "msg": "OK",
  "crawlId": "crawl01"
}
```

Bottom line you need to create a new configuration with the `solr.server.url` setted instead of specifying it through the `args` key in the JSON payload.